# Sort flat, associative array by values in a descending direction

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to figure out how to sort the results after counting variables inside an array. Below is the list I get and I want to sort it by $value (which I will the explode). How can I make the lost below in order of $value, ie. 7,8 would be at the top of the list?

Variables in array & **$values**(in bold)

11,6 ------ **1**

9,8 ------- **1**

9,6 ------- **2**

7,8 ------- **4**

This is how I am counting the variables within the array and trying to sort.

```
//Count variables
$newArray = array_count_values($myArray);
asort($value);
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong><br />"; 
}
print_r(array_count_values($myArray));
```

This is how the array is created.

```
$myArray = array();
$sql="SELECT pic_id FROM pics";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $myArray[]=$row['pic_id'];  
}
```

Comment: WTF does the array actually look like?  That makes no sense.  Maybe `print_r`.

Comment: It looks like this [7] => 11,6 [8] => 9,8 [9] => 9,6 [10] => 7,8 [11] => 9,11 [12] => 8,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
asort($value);
```

with (for ascending order of the keys of $newArray)

```
sort($newArray);
```

or with (for descending order of the values of $newArray):

```
arsort($newArray);
```

In both cases "7,8" is at the top.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction.

```
$arr = [ 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3 ];

$count = count($arr);
```

// $count is equal to 3

```
$sort = arsort($arr);
```

// $sort is equal to [ 2 => 3, 1 => 2, 0 => 1]

Answer (score 0):

Provided that I have correctly understood your question, you need to have an new array with the values in $myArray (pic_id) sorted by their occurrences in descending order. The following code should work:

```
$newArray = array_count_values($myArray);

arsort($newArray);

$v = array_keys($newArray);

print_r($v);
```

The resulting $v array is zero indexed array consisting of the elements in $myArray as follows:

```
7,8  9,6  9,8  11,6
```